# Need explanation about for-loop code in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I found a python "for loop" code online and its syntax differs from other codes. I would like to know about:

1. Why is the 'key' in front of the for loop?
2. Why is there an `if` statement inline?

CODE:

```
input = "codeforcode" 
freqDict = Counter(input)
freq1 = [ key for (key,count) in freqDict.items() if count==1]
```

Further, I would like to have web links to understand "for loop" more in-depth in python.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

> A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression
>   followed by a `for` clause, then zero or more `for` or `if` clauses. The
>   result will be a new list resulting from evaluating the expression in
>   the context of the for and if clauses which follow it. For example,
>   this listcomp combines the elements of two lists if they are not
>   equal:
>
> ```
> >>> [(x, y) for x in [1,2,3] for y in [3,1,4] if x != y]
> [(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 1), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 4)]
> ```

That `for` loop you have

```
[ key for (key,count) in freqDict.items() if count==1]
```

is equivalent to:

```
keys = []
for key, count in freqDict.items():
    if count == 1:
        keys.append(key)
```

The regular `for` loop that you probably know is still valid in Python, nothing is changed there. Using list comprehensions "*provides a more concise way to create lists*" as the `for` loop/s and the `if` condition are all put into a single line, and also, you don't need to create a temporary variable for storing the resulting list.

Comment: yeah i understood .thanks

Comment: @nishanth Great :) BTW, here in StackOverflow, if an answer helped you, you have the option of [upvoting the answer and/or marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).